# "aspnet_compiler.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, msbuild

We have suddenly come across the following error on building one of our ASP.NET projects on a specific machine:

```
"aspnet_compiler.exe" exited with code 1.
```

We have tried:

- cleaning / rebuilding the solution
- deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders
- restarting Visual Studio
- restarting the machine
- clearing the temporary files
- deleting the `.suo` and `.user` files
- reset all settings to defaults -- Web Development (Code only)

We initially had this issue using Visual Studio 2013, but it still persists after upgrading to VS 2015 Update 1, with ASP.NET 5 RC1.

Other projects compile successfully on this machine, and the same project compiles successfully on other machines.

What steps can we take to debug this issue, and how can we resolve it?

Comment: Have you looked at the output produced by the compiler: `Ctrl+W+O`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Do you mean the Output pane? Nothing stands out. What should I be looking for?

Comment: yeah, look at the output of the compiler and more specifically the lines preceding the error.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov We have a post-build event that deletes a few files that we don't want when we publish; those files don't exist when we build in a simple debug, and the output window outputs that those files are not found.

Comment: if you add the command line option    -errorstack   to the aspnet_compiler run, apparently this will output some error info

Answer (score 0):

After running Windows Update, the problem was resolved.